# Anchor tag with download attribute opens file instead of downloading

Tags: html, reactjs

In my Reactjs application I used the anchor tag to download a txt file like below.

```
<a href="http://textfiles.com/......./sample.txt" download>download</a>
```

There I added **download** attribute to force it to download instead open it in the browser tab.

But it is still opening in the same tab instead of downloading. Can any one help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Are you using `webpack` or `create-react-app`?

Comment: @Abinthaha I'm using create-react-app

Comment: You need to `import` the file before adding it in anchor tag. You can't use direct links.

Answer (score 16):

Looking at your example seems you're not using same origin and that might have cause the problem.

If you're trying to download the file which exists in same origin then I suggest you to use relative url rather than absolute url.

Example:

```
<a href="/public/sample.txt" download>download</a>
```

Please take a look at the note from [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#Attributes):

Attribute: **download**

> **Notes:**
>
> - This attribute only works for [same-origin URLs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy).
> - Although HTTP(s) URLs need to be in the same-origin, [blob: URLs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL.createObjectURL) and
>   [data: URLs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs) are allowed so that content generated by JavaScript, such
>   as pictures created in an image-editor Web app, can be downloaded.
> - If the HTTP header [Content-Disposition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition): gives a different filename
>   than this attribute, the HTTP header takes priority over this
>   attribute.
> - If Content-Disposition: is set to inline, Firefox prioritizes
>   Content-Disposition, like the filename case, while Chrome prioritizes
>   the download attribute.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Bhojendra Rauniyar. Got the best answer

Answer (score -3):

Try like this

```
import File from 'http://textfiles.com/......./sample.txt'; //Or the path could be any relative path to the local file.

//Other code
render() {
    return(
        //Code
        <a href={File} download>download</a>
    )
}
```

But inorder to use like this, you should be confident that you will get the file without any issues. Better to download the file and access it from your own directory instead of calling from another server.