# Download Image with url React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, download

Im working on a picture gallery.
Im trying to make a mechanism that allows user to press button and download image.
I have a url to the image. How can I do this?

Comment: did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Use download attribute of link tag:

```
<a href="path-to-image.jpg" download>
  <img src="path-to-image.jpg" />
</a>
```

Also, take care as this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52089582/2138752) statement while using download attribute.

Comment: hi thanks! Its not downloading only opening it in new page. The url looks look this:https://farm2.staticflickr.com/1871/44381239451_8e000b4b26.jpg

Comment: Did you check the linked post?

Comment: im working on a local host so the relative path wont work

Comment: That's a good thing not an issue with relative path. Check this https://superuser.com/questions/836345/why-is-my-chrome-failing-to-download-some-files

Comment: it says no file dont think chrome is the issue

Comment: how are you defining the path?

Comment: i tried all subpaths 1871/44381239451_8e000b4b26.jpg, 44381239451_8e000b4b26.jpg, farm2.staticflickr.com/1871/44381239451_8e000b4b26.jpg

Comment: I'm sure you have problem defining the path. What's your root path

Answer (score 0):

To download the image in react create a new download button component and pass the image path as a prop to that component. You will have to do something similar to the this:-

```
  import React, { useState } from 'react';
interface DownloadButtonProps{
path:string
}
const DownloadButton<DownloadButtonProps> = (props) => {
  const [imageUrl] = useState(props.path); // Replace with the actual path to your image

  const handleDownloadClick = () => {
    // Create a Blob object for the image
    fetch(imageUrl)
      .then((response) => response.blob())
      .then((blob) => {
        // Create a URL for the Blob
        const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

        // Create an anchor element for downloading
        const a = document.createElement('a');
        a.href = url;
        a.download = 'downloaded-image.jpg'; // Specify the desired download filename

        // Programmatically trigger a click event on the anchor element
        a.click();

        // Clean up by revoking the URL
        URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
      });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleDownloadClick}>Download Image</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default DownloadButton;
```