# Downloading a file from a url in react

Tags: reactjs, web, flicker, download

I'm trying to learn reactJS and as a part of it I`m trying to let my users images from a URL of a photo (using flicker API)

I browsed here for a solution and the closest I got is here:
[Download Image with url React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52114477/download-image-with-url-react)

unfortunately using the `<a href={url} download>` to initiate the download when the button is pressed does not work.
is there a way to make my browser initiate the download? does it not work because flicker API does not support that kind of features?

Comment: is the url  an absolute or relative path?

Comment: @DevDwarf the url is an absolute path, and is on a remote host (Flicker web site)

Comment: look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/52089582/9897598