# HTML download attribute won't work: acts as normal link

Tags: javascript, html, rest, flask, web

This dosen't work in chrome nor firefox. What I'm trying to do is get the logo of a discord server and let the user download it. My python backend succesfully did the first part, so I don't think that's the problem. My HTML code below has the download button inside a link. Everything works, except instead of downloading the image I just get to a page with the link. I've tried the other answers on this site, but I could not find something that worked for me.

My HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <!-- Bootstrap's CSS stylesheet -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-KyZXEAg3QhqLMpG8r+8fhAXLRk2vvoC2f3B09zVXn8CA5QIVfZOJ3BCsw2P0p/We" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <!-- My CSS stylesheet -->
    <link href="{{ url_for('static',filename='css/style.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" />
    <title>Discord Profile Picture</title>
    <!-- Google Fonts -->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body class="text-white">
    <div class="bg">
        <div id="main">
            <p class="roboto fifty">Discord server invite:</p>
            <!-- Text Input using Bootstrap -->
            <div class="input-group mb-3">
                <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon3">
                    discord.gg/</span>
                <input type="text" placeholder="XXXXXXXX" class="form-control" id="basic-url"
                    aria-describedby="basic-addon3" />
                <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button" id="button-addon2" onClick="send()">
                    Send
                </button>
            </div>
            <a id="download-link">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg">Download</button>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- My JS Script -->
    <script src="{{ url_for('static',filename='js/script.js') }}"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap's JS Script -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-U1DAWAznBHeqEIlVSCgzq+c9gqGAJn5c/t99JyeKa9xxaYpSvHU5awsuZVVFIhvj"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

My JS:

```js
function send() {
    var data = {
        invite: document.getElementById("basic-url").value
    };
    console.log("Sent.")
    fetch("/scrape", {
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json',},
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
    }).then(res => res.json()).then(data => {
        downloadLink = document.getElementById("download-link")
        downloadLink.style.display = "unset"; downloadLink.href = data; downloadLink.download = data
    })

}
```

My Python backend:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

app = Flask(__name__)

# Web Page


@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return render_template('index.html')

# RESTful api endpoint


@app.route("/scrape", methods=["POST"])
def scrape():
    code = request.get_json()["invite"]
    invite = requests.get(f"https://discord.gg/{code}").text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(invite, features="html.parser")
    for meta_tag in soup.find_all("meta"):
        try:
            if meta_tag["property"] == "og:image":
                return jsonify(meta_tag["content"]), 200
        except KeyError:
            pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

And my CSS

```css
body, html { height: 100% }

/* Center everything */
#main {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

/* Roboto text */
p.roboto.fifty {
    font-family : 'Roboto',
    sans-serif;
    font-size: 40px;
    padding-left: 15px;
}

.parent { position: relative }

/* Full screen background */
#background-image {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

/* Background */
.bg {
    background-image: url("../images/background.png");
    height: 100%;
    
    /* Center and scale the image nicely */
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

#download-link {
    padding-left: 35%;
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: Maybe it's due to the invalid HTML, ["_Permitted content: Transparent, except that __no descendant may be interactive content or an \[interactive\] element__, and no descendant may have a specified tabindex attribute._"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a).

Comment: You should not have a button inside an anchor element. Give the anchor element all the classes that you gave to your button, and remove the button. For accessibility purposes, you should add `role="button"` to it as well.

Comment: Thanks, I did that, but it still does the same as before.

Comment: Can you share the link that it goes to after you click on download? Is it just an image link or something else?

Comment: It's an image link. The way the page works is that you put the discord invite and it gets the link of the server icon. Here's the link for the specific server I was testing: https://cdn.discordapp.com/icons/830592909001621545/6e1f3aa4aebc0cd135621e19f4b2c88e.jpg?size=256 @SiddharthBhansali

Comment: Hmm, I did some searching and found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52089417/anchor-tag-with-download-attribute-opens-file-instead-of-downloading , this basically lists rules, one of which states that the file linked needs to be same origin, which means it should be on the same server as the website. 3rd party URLs will just open in a new tab as they are now happening for you.

Comment: I see. I'm not sure how I'd go about fixing it, then.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239208/discussion-between-fors-and-siddharth-bhansali).

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use `downloadLink.setAttribute("download", data)` instead of `downloadLink.download = data`.

that should work

Comment: It didn't work. It's the same as before. It might be noteworthy that I don't have a button and basically made my anchor tag a button, but I doubt that affected anything.